# tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator random_transform does not perform rescale

Tags: tensorflow, google-colaboratory, tf.keras

I am using colab and tf version is '2.2.0-rc2'. Using tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator to perform a single random transform using .[random_transform](https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/keras/preprocessing/image/ImageDataGenerator#random_transform) on a single image does not rescale it (with 1/255.) Code snippet:

```
import tensorflow as tf
import PIL

img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(rescale=1./255)
img = PIL.Image.open("my_image.jpg")
img = img.resize((224, 224), PIL.Image.BICUBIC)
img_t = img_gen.random_transform(np.array(img))
```

img_t is still a tensor with range [0, 255] instead of [0.0, 1.0].

Is this by design or this is a bug? I don't remember the behavior before tensorflow 2.0 (i probably never use it that way).

Note: I don't see any issue if I use .flow or .flow_from_directory and their generators.

Comment: This probably not a bug. My simple fix is to do this: img_t = img_t*img_gen.rescale

Answer (score 1):

It looks to me like does make sense. `flow` or `flow_from_*` methods and `random_transform()` transforms data differently.

- The `flow()` methods will take the configuration/transformations provided to ImageDataGenerator and spit out data according to those parameters
- `random_transform()` comes up with a random transformation configuration (based on the parameters you've setup in `__init__` of your `ImageDataGenerator` and apply that to the data. This means your `rescale` parameter might be overridden by default.

### More info on `random_transform()`

I haven't used `random_tranform()` myself before. But it seems this is how it works.

Let's say we define the following `ImageDataGenerator`

```
img_gen = tf.keras.preprocessing.image.ImageDataGenerator(
    rescale=1./255, vertical_flip=True, brightness_range=(-0.1,0.1)
)
```

Now you can see what kind of random transformations are available using,

```
print(img_gen.get_random_transform((1,224,224,3)))
```

which will give different random values for `vertical_flip` and `brightness`. As you can see `rescale` is apparently not a random parameter they consider. This explains why you didn't get the expected result.

Comment: I also took a look at keras src code, it is consistent with what you said. The behavior is per design, probably not a bug. My bias towards this being a bug in the 1st place is in the context of what I was trying. I used this data augmentation generator and pass this into a tf.tensorflow.keras.utils.Sequence subclass to enable data augmentation when using a Sequence (supposedly good for multi-proc?). And i was caught by surprise by image wasnt scaled. But I have a workaround, see my comment in the Q.